# Excel document didn't get generated in windows server 2012 R2 using c#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, oracle11g, automation

I have one automation(windows application) which used to export data form database to excel document. This is developed using c# and hosted in window server 2012 R2. Here we have installed office 14( Microsoft excel 2010 ) and its version is 14.0.7162.5000(32-bit) same version dll is used in automation also.
Problem is excel document is not generated and there is no error in log also. Every time when automation ran excel process is created in task manager but excel document not get generated.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Code part is perfect. Bcoz we have tested same automation in development environment it works fine. Excel document get generated.

Comment: It fails in prod environment

Comment: Than we are not able to help you because we can't reproduce your issue.
Have you checked the rights you have of where you want to write? Or is it another outputpath you didn't thought of?

Comment: Even we have used admin rights but no luck...